# How to call a delegate without its reference in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using a third party library, which has structure as following.

```
@protocol ZipArchiveDelegate;

@interface Main: NSObject

//All static methods are declared here
+ (BOOL)unzipFileAtPath:(NSString *)path
          toDestination:(NSString *)destination
               delegate:(id<ZipArchiveDelegate>) delegate;


//There is no reference of this delegate, while it is calling delegate methods in .m class
@end



@protocol ZipArchiveDelegate <NSObject>
@optional

- (void)someWorkEnded;

@end
```

Now when I need to call this method, I am calling it inside a UIViewController Subcalss. As I pass delegate as self, it gives warning that "Incompitible Pointer Types sending class to parameter of Type `id<ZipArchiveDelegate>`"

```
[Main unzipFileAtPath:zipLocalPath toDestination:toDestination delegate:self];
```

How can I call it, as there is no static method, so I am using "Main", the Class Name for calling methods.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you declare your subclass as conforming to ZipArchiveDelegate protocol? It should be like this - YourViewController:UIViewController < ZipArchiveDelegate>

Comment: if you have a delegate that should respond to messages, add a reference. otherwise nil... make sure the delegate you add as reference corresponds to the non-optional delegate messages.

Comment: @kirander, Yes I have done <ZipArchiveDelegate> but issue is something else.

Comment: Why should I pass nil, I want to pass my controller so it should give me response /calling delegate methods in my current controller @Volker

Comment: It is expecting something else than self. so how can I pass its own delegate object from my current class.

Comment: It is expecting any type (id) conforming to ZipArchiveDelegate (<ZipArchiveDelegate>). Thats all.

Comment: Still giving warning, thats what I am asking. and not calling any of method also, I pasted all methods, put log in them.

Comment: Show the method in your view controller that has the line `[Main unzipFileAtPath:zipLocalPath toDestination:toDestination delegate:self];` in it. The method unzipFileAtPath:toDestination:delegate: is a class method, so you nee to call it on the Main class, which you are doing. If you are calling it from an instance method of your view controller that code should work. The error message you are getting suggests to me that you are calling it from a class method instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in a class method yourself thats why it won't work. When inside a `+` declared method `self` points to te class not a instance. The method call wants a instance conforming to ZipArchiveDelegate.